# How to deserialize Json to object

Tags: json, serialization

I've got a problem with Deserializing a JSON Object. This is the JSON I have:

```
{
    "resource": [{
        "ClienteNome": "DOUGLAS DA SILVA BENEDITO",
        "ClienteStatus": 0
    }, {
        "ClienteNome": "MARCO AURELIO DE SÁ GONÇALVES",
        "ClienteStatus": 1
    }, {
        "ClienteNome": "MATHEUS CELESTINO CANDIDO",
        "ClienteStatus": 2
    }]
}
```

I'm trying to deserialize it this way

```
public static async Task<List<Model.ClientesOnline>> GetAsync()
{
     using (var client = new HttpClient())
     {
          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-DreamFactory-Api-Key", "36fda24fe5588fa4285ac6c6c2fdfbdb6b64699774c9bf777f706d05a88");
          string json = await client.GetStringAsync("http://api-u16.cloudapp.net/api/v2/nova207/_table/vw_clientes_online");

          var clientesonline = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model.ClientesOnline>>(json);
          return clientesonline;
     }
}
```

model

```
namespace NovaCloud.Model
{
    class ClientesOnline : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {


        [JsonProperty("Resorces")]
        private string clientenome;
        public string ClienteNome { get { return clientenome; }
            set
            {
                clientenome = value;
                this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ClienteNome)));
            }
        }

        private string clientestatus;
        public string ClienteStatus { get { return clientestatus; }
            set
            {
                clientestatus = value;
                this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ClienteStatus)));
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    }
}
```

Error message

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,Linker.Class.alternatives]'
>   because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to
>   deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a
>   JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to
>   an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g.
>   ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON array.

I've tried in several ways

Comment: You have to change your model class. If you not sure your model is correct check it with json2csharp. (http://json2csharp.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Your model is wrong, you are expecting an object not a list, This is what the model should like:

```
public class Resource
{
    public string ClienteNome { get; set; }
    public int ClienteStatus { get; set; }
}

public class ClientsOnline
{
    public List<Resource> resource { get; set; }
}
```

And when you deserialize you should do something like this:

```
var clientsOnline= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClientesOnline>(json);
```